# Is there a known issue with HTTPS and the Android browser?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, browser, https

I have a Galaxy S2 running 2.3.3, all up to date and not rooted.  On several sites I find that logging in is impossible due to requests sent on HTTPS not returning a response.

I've not tested the issue exhaustively, but the most notable failures for me are my Natwest online banking and signing in to Stack Exchange sites with my Google ID.  In both these cases the response from the server never appears, in the case of Stack sites this happens when clicking the 'Log in with Google' button, I never even get a chance to enter credentials.

I've resorted to using Opera Mobile for now, and since this works fine it seems to be an issue localised to the android default browser.  Is there a way of fixing it, or should I just choose a different browser and set that as default instead?

Comment: You mean Android by "droid", yes?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue described with the stock android browser, I think you may have had a "hiccup" in data connectivity or something.

Comment: Sorry, I do mean Android, thanks for the correction

Comment: @Ryan: it's not a hiccup, it's been a consistent issue since I got the phone in May.

Comment: I have this issue with the Power School site for my kids' school. I can't login via any Android device: Droid Inc, CM7 Nook or ASUS Transformer. But I also had issues with FF and that site as well. I was told to uncheck "use TLS 1.0" security protocol and that made FF work but there is not equivalent option for the Android browsers. I also have this issue with Dolphin HD but I haven't tried any other browsers yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any widely known issue with this. I am able to sign in to StackExchange automatically on my Nexus S. I looked around at the [Android Issue Tracker](http://b.android.com/) and while there are a lot of results for ["browser https"](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=browser%20https&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), none in the first 20 or so seemed pertinent.

It might just be a problem local to your phone. I'd try resetting it.

Comment: I did do a factory reset in the end as I started to have unusual issues with battery life. After a reset and full update, everything seems to be working fine.